# Determing length of each row in a matrix based on entry of said row in first column

Tags: r, matrix

This has probably already been answered somewhere, but since I cannot describe what I need well enough for it to appear on google, I'll try it this way.

Basically what I have is a column, this is just an example, I need it done on much larger scale:

```
col <- c(2,5,4,3,4)
```

Now I want to use cbind to create a matrix where the first column is `col`. The rows of this matrix are then filled using rnorm, but only up to the length of the value entered in the first column, i.e. it should look like this.

```
> mat
  
2 rnorm rnorm NA    NA    NA
5 rnorm rnorm rnorm rnorm rnorm 
4 rnorm rnorm rnorm rnorm NA
3 rnorm rnorm rnorm NA    NA
4 rnorm rnorm rnorm rnorm NA
```

I know how to achieve this using for loops, but I want to avoid these in order to keep the running time low. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two methods to create a `matrix` from the output of `lapply`, one using `rbind` and another using `unlist`

```
set.seed(7)

c1 <- c(2,5,4,3,4)

l1 <- lapply(c1,
             function(x, y) head(c(rnorm(x), rep(NA, y)), y),
             y = max(c1))

m1 <- matrix(unlist(l1),
             ncol = max(c1),
             byrow = TRUE)

m2 <- do.call(rbind, l1)

# set row names
rownames(m1) <- c1
rownames(m2) <- c1

        [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]      [,5]
2  2.2872472 -1.1967717         NA         NA        NA
5 -0.6942925 -0.4122930 -0.9706733 -0.9472799 0.7481393
4 -0.1169552  0.1526576  2.1899781  0.3569862        NA
3  2.7167518  2.2814519  0.3240205         NA        NA
4  1.8960671  0.4676805 -0.8938007 -0.3073283        NA
```

This can also be accomplished in one step using `sapply`.  However, the output is transposed when compared to the above.  It's possible to use `t` but that becomes expensive if the matrix is large.

```
m3 <- sapply(c1,
             function(x, y) head(c(rnorm(x), rep(NA, y)), y),
             y = max(c1))

colnames(m3) <- c1
```

Here is an example to conditionally set `matrix` values based on a condition:

```
t1 <- 0.59

m1[m1 > t1] <- t1
m1[m1 < t1] <- 0

  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
2 0.59 0.00   NA   NA   NA
5 0.00 0.00 0.00    0 0.59
4 0.00 0.00 0.59    0   NA
3 0.59 0.59 0.00   NA   NA
4 0.59 0.00 0.00    0   NA
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Quick follow up question though. I also need to set the values in this matrix that are above a threshold to said threshold and equal to zero under another condition. Is this easy to incorporate in the function?

Comment: @LuukS Updated answer with example to conditionally modify the matrix

Comment: Thank you! I have one last question, then I won't bother you anymore. In my final matrix I have an additional column at the end of the matrix containing the thresholds for each row, so each row has a different threshold. Furthermore, if these thresholds are below a newly generated matrix of equals size to the original matrix, containing ```runif```` numbers, I set the value of the original matrix in that entry to zero. How should I tackle this?

Comment: @LuukS That's a substantial shift from the original question.  The threshold by row would need to be incorporated into the original `lapply` or iterated through the output `matrix` with `apply`.  The comparison `matrix` should by similar to the answer above but comparing each `matrix` to get a logical vector.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61622588/comparing-rows-of-matrix-and-replacing-matching-elements

Comment: Thank you! You've helped me enormously!